# Performance issue when using multiple parallel queries - SqlClient

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, task-parallel-library

I've noticed performance issue with my application after changing server and trying to increase number of worker threads for some db intensive tasks.

After some tests i've found that the problem is with reading data from dataReader. Executing simple query on 30 threads takes at least 15 times slower then on single thread. Using PerfView I found that most of time is wasted on BLOCKED_TIME.

For tests I use server with Ryzen Threadripper (32cores/64threads) with local instance of SqlServer. Same results on production server with similar specification.

I've tried run 30 instances of application - there was almost no difference in performance between 2-3 and 30 instances, so server performance is good enough to carry 30 parallel queries.

I've tried some changes in connection string like increase/decrese min/max pool size, disable pooling, change LCP to TCP - with no result.

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ids = new List<Guid>() { ... }; //filled by database ids 
            var stats = new ConcurrentBag<long>();

            //warmup
            stats.Add(TestMethod());

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("|{0}|{1,5}ms|", "warmup", stats.Average()));

            //start 1 to 30 threads (test on server with 32 cores / 64 threads)
            for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
            {
                stats = new ConcurrentBag<long>();
                var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, i).Select(idx =>
                {
                    var id = ids[idx]; // separate ids to be sure we're not reading same records from disk
                    return Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                        {
                            stats.Add(TestMethod(id));
                        }
                    });
                }).ToArray();

                Task.WaitAll(tasks);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("|{0,2}|{1,5}ms|", i, (int)stats.Average()));

            }

            Console.WriteLine("End");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


        private static long TestMethod()
        {
            var records = new List<object[]>();
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.Transaction = transaction;
                    command.CommandText = SqlQuery;
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("id", id));

                    // measure only dataReader time
                    sw.Start();
                    using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        // got ~2000 rows from query
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            //read all data from row, test on Guid
                            var values = new object[6];
                            dataReader.GetValues(values);
                            records.Add(values);
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Stop();
                }
            }
            return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
```

Is there any way to increase performance and make my app scalable with number of threads?

---

edit.
Db structure and example query to reproduce:

```sql
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table_1]    Script Date: 05.07.2019 14:08:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Ref1] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Field1] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Field2] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table_2]    Script Date: 05.07.2019 14:08:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_2](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Field1] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IDX_Table_1_Ref1]    Script Date: 05.07.2019 14:08:15 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Table_1_Ref1] ON [dbo].[Table_1]
(
    [Ref1] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Field1],
    [Field2]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table_1_Table_2] FOREIGN KEY([Ref1])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table_2] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table_1_Table_2]
GO
```

```sql
select  
    t2.id as Id,
    t2.Field1 as Field1,
    t1.Id as T1_Id,
    t1.Ref1 as T1_T2,
    t1.Field1 as T1_Field1,
    t1.Field2 as T1_Field2
from dbo.Table_2 t2
join dbo.Table_1 t1 on t1.Ref1 = t2.Id
where t2.id = @id
```

There id now 30 records in T1 and 2000 * 30 records in T1, so each thread works on same dataset with 30records. Data filled with random newid().

---

edit2.

I also compared this solution in cases - 30 separate processes vs 1 process and 30 threads on Sql Server. 30 separate processes works fine - its like 150% of original execution time, not 1500%. 
Most differences - with 30 separate processes and single thread i got ~14 waiting tasks and 20k batch requests / sec, with single process and 30 threads i got > 30 waiting tasks (mostly on Network I/O) and 2k batch requests / sec.

---

Setting

```
"System.GC.Server": true
```

solved my issue, now it scales up to the maximum available threads on the server. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "increase number of worker threads for some **db** **intensive** **tasks**" It is highly probable that you may face table locks. Check SSMS database monitor (resource waits) and check for infrastructure problems (network, io) and database problems (locks, latch). You can also launch SQL Server Profiler to monitor database locks and see what is blocking what.

Comment: If you have one thread bottle-necking your db, what makes you think multiple threads are going to help? Also,you are probably running out of thread pool threads because you are doing IO on them (which is the wrong thing to do anyway). Lastly you should probably look at efficiencies in your sql, query plan, or indexes, or using builk inserts and updates, before trying to solve a problem by creating more problems

Comment: Which version/edition of sql server is used and how many worker threads are set on the database level?

Comment: The old saying (i just made up) goes *"I had a problem, then i tried to create 30 threads to solve them, now i have even more problems"*

Comment: Running a bad query in parallel won't make it go faster. It will make it go a lot *slower*, as blocking will *increase*. Even with a well written query, what are you trying to parallelize? The server's disks, RAM, CPU are still the same. Your *machine's* network card and bandwidth are still the same, so you won't get any performance boost unless you have multiple network cards

Comment: Locking on DB isn't the problem. For this case i use only simple Select with Snapshot Isolation, also runnig same test with single thread and 30 processes (so number of parallel queries is same) works fine.

Comment: TPL and parallelism have nothing to do with query performance. *SQL Server* already uses parallel execution - in Enterprise automatically, in Standard based on query hints. The code you posted isn't relevant. What does the *query* look like? What is its execution plan? How many rows are there?

Comment: For db we use developer version od Sql Server 2017, currently max worker threads: 1472.

Comment: @DominikCzerwiński `Locking on DB` is exactly what the problem is about. That's why you see so much `BLOCKED_TIME`. Use SSMS's Activity Monitor to see what's going on on your server. You'll see 30 sessions all blocking each other or waiting

Comment: @DominikCzerwiński which means the queries are **already** using parallel execution plans. Developer has the same features as Enterprise. By using multiple queries you only increase blocking. Again, what are your queries? Table schemas? Execution plans?

Comment: For test i got simple SELECT query with 1 join statements (Index Seek for both join and PK filtering)

Comment: @DominikCzerwiński please post the relevant code (ie SQL queries) instead of describing it. *Small* queries will benefit from concurrent execution, since they won't have to pay the full network roundtrip overhead, at the cost of increased contention. That's how web apps work. Batching multiple statements together though is *far* faster than concurrent execution. There's only a single round trip and limited contention. That's how ETL scripts work. Large queries *always* suffer from concurrent execution

Comment: @DominikCzerwiński as for testing, the code you posted is full of perf issues and probably causes all blocking. For example adding items to a List leads to buffer reallocations. The wrong parallelism model is used - PLINQ is meant for parallel data computation, not concurrent execution and thus uses *all cores all the time*. If you run this code on the database server itself you'll be competing with it for CPU time

Comment: @DominikCzerwiński `most of time is wasted on BLOCKED_TIME.` that's probably the 64 threads used by `Parallel.For` waiting for the database to respond, while *it* in turn is waiting for those 64 threads to be suspended so it can process the query

Comment: @DominikCzerwiński `to carry 30 parallel queries.` it's not 30, it's **64** executed *sequentially* 30 times. `Parallel.For` doesn't start *a* thread. It uses as many threads as cores to process its input data, including the *current* thread, that's why it's a blocking operation. It partitions the input into as many partitions  as threads and feeds each partition to a single thread. For computations on lots of data, that's the most efficient way to work. For IO operations on the other hand, it's a waste of CPU time as all threads will block waiting for the IO to complete

Comment: I know how Parallel works, i added that to test on my pc with less number of cores. Same result on Task.Run or using ThreadPool directly.

I've updated my code with example database structure and query that behave excatly same like my production app. I'm actualy testing on that example.

When i run my code (example above) i got:
5 threads - 300% original time,
10 threads - 500%, 
20 threads - 1000%, 
30 threads - 1500%.
As i said before, i can run 30 apps and there is no performance issue on that, so server can handle that load easly.

Comment: You know how Parrellel.For works? How do you think it works, what is your expectations here?

Comment: @TheGeneral Partition workload over available resources, so in worst cases i finish in sequential execution. But its not the point of my question - same result without that :)

Comment: One thing i noticed after comparing parallel execution as TASKS vs PROCESSES - when i run separate processes i got much lower Waiting Tasks on Sqlserver, mostly in Network I/O section (30 separate processes ~12, single process and multithread ~30). Also i got 20k Batch requests/s for separate processes and 2k for multithread). Maybe there is some limitation for single process?

Comment: In no particular order: test what happens if you use unique connection strings (i.e. `Application Name=myapp{number}`, turn off MARS if it's turned on in the connection string, use `Packet Size=32767`, use the `Async` versions of the methods, recompile the whole thing for .NET Core (and use the new `System.Data.SqlClient` package). It is just about possible you're hitting some interesting internal bottleneck in the thread pool or the TDS code, but it would be hard to pinpoint without profiling. "Normal" applications don't have 30 parallel `DataReader`s going on, that's for certain.

Comment: I've compiled it for .net451/461/471 as well as for .net core 2.1 with no difference, as well as changing System.Data.SqlClient for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. I will try async version of methods, but if process is throttled by some configuration i guess it will only makes my code muchs lower in "normal cases".
30 parallel `DataReader`s is nothing strange when u hit with web apps, but usually in separate pools, not in single app/process.

Comment: Oh, and use `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` in your query to ensure you don't have parallel-on-parallel action, as that's not helpful in any case (you are already maxing out core use). This may well be effectively testing how well thread switching works when applied to separate processes vs. separate threads, but that's not quite the same as testing the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your GC settings.

https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1471/garbage-collection-csharp-dotnet-core

Setting parameters

```
ServerGarbageCollection = true
ConcurrentGarbageCollection = false
```

may help. :)